# Choosing the shunt resistor value and capacitor for op-amp integrator based on input resistance and DC gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrator

[image: the problem circuit]

I think it's option C based on C = 1/R and the R2 as 10 times R1 but apparently the answer is option A.
Please tell me where i'm going wrong.
The full question reads

> The following figure shows opamp-based integrator circuit. If this circuit were to integrate a symmetrical pulse waveform ...

Comment: The DC gain is 100.

Comment: R2 as 10 times R1 has G=10. If you want G=100 you need R2 100 times R1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DC gain requirement (ignore the capacitor) requires the shunt resistor to be 1M for a DC gain of -100.

The capacitor is found from half the waveform (100us) times a rule of thumb multiplier of 5 to 10, and we will use 10, for a time constant of 1ms= R1*C.

Comment: But using 1ms = R1*C should be C = 1ms/R1 and that's not 0.1uF

Comment: If you check your arithmetic I think you will find it is.

Comment: Got it 
Thanks for the help :)